# Swap yoda conditions strings in all files

Tags: text-processing, sed

In my C project I have all conditions (almost 20.000 ones) written with yoda-condition coding style and I want to change this in all files.
For example I have:

```
if (0 == ret)
if (0 == rc)
if (0 != ret)
if (100 == other_variable)
```

Is there a generic way to swap the left and the right variables in all occurences? (replace "x == y" with "y == x")

At least for the majority of them, the other ones I can do them manually.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -E -i 's/if \((.*) == (.*)\)/if \(\2 == \1\)/' file
```

change the code for your other operator.

[How to use sed to replace regex capture group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30431410/6893835)

Comment: Great, thanks! Now I only have to change it a little bit to work with multiple conditions like "if (a == true && c == false)"

Comment: if you like view the difference before you write the file: `diff <(cat file) <(sed -E 's/if \((.*) == (.*)\)/if \(\2 == \1\)/' file` you can replace diff with vimdiff for better UI and in the second subshell you can use more sed commands with `... file | sed -E 's/....`

Comment: The diff is no problem, cause I can use meld before commiting to git, now I am trying to fix multiple conditions, like the one above.Thanks again for the solution, it's a great place to start.:)